# PHP shortest regular expression for empty string

Tags: php, preg-match, shortest

I want to find the shortest possible regular expression pattern to match an empty string(no whitespacer or anything at all)

I have found

```
 /(\d|)/    (7chars)
and '^[\s]*$' (9 chars)
```

till now.

Comment: An empty string? As in zero characters? Or a string with no alphabet characters?

Comment: This  answer for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833999/regular-expression-to-match-an-empty-or-all-whitespace-string) might help.

Comment: after asking a question, please attempt to not change the entire context of your question. if you have a different question, delete this one and try again.

Answer (score 6):

Technically `/(\d|)/` is 5 characters, the slashes are just delimiters.

The shortest regex I know of that would match an empty string is `^$`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a regex if you can use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) ? i.e.:

```
$emptyStr = "";

if(empty($emptyStr)){
   echo "I'm empty";
}
```

you guessed, it outputs "*I'm empty*".